# ClassCastException on enum toString

Tags: java, junit

Can anyone explain why the following JUnit test will fail with a ClassCastException: Message cannot be cast to java.lang.String in the Assert statement below?

```
    public enum Message{
        NULL_REQUEST("Null Request"),
        INVALID_NUMBER_OF_REQUESTS("Invalid number of requests");

        Message(String msg){
            this.msg = msg;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return msg;
        }
        private final String msg;
    }
```

Then the test class has:

```
@Test
public void test(){
    String x = Message.INVALID_NUMBER_OF_REQUESTS.toString();
    Assert.assertEquals(x, "actual value" );
}
```

Comment: Correct, I've updated the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cxfquest,

your code has (had) some errors, please correct it.

The following code works for me:

```
public class MyTestUnit {

    public enum Message{
        NULL_REQUEST("Null Request"),
        INVALID_NUMBER_OF_REQUESTS("Invalid number of requests");

        Message(String msg){
            this.msg = msg;
        }

        private final String msg;

        public String getMsg() {
            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return msg;
        }


    }

    @Test
    public void test(){
        String x = Message.INVALID_NUMBER_OF_REQUESTS.toString();
        Assert.assertEquals(x, "actual value" );
    }

}
```

I think you are not compiling and you are running an old version (maybe).

Result is:

> org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[Invalid number of requests]>
>   but was:<[actual value]>

as expected.

Comment: Yes instead of "actual value" there was business logic which i assumed returned a string, but instead was a Message object.  Thanks for the sanity check